# How to recall function under jquery plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have created one jQuery plugin to use in my own system. The problem: I would like the system to update every 1 second. Normally I recall the function by use `setTimeout` with the name of its function. But now when I use in jQuery it does not work. What's wrong with it and how can I solve it?

```
(function($){
$.fn.OnlineBox = function(options){
    var user={};
    var container = this;

    user.id=$(container).children("id").text();
    user.name=$(container).children("name").text();
    user.sip=$(container).children("sip").text();
    user.session=$(container).children("session").text();
    user.ip=$(container).children("ip").text();

    var func={
        updateStatus : function(){
            $.ajax({
                url: "libs/online.php",
                type: "POST",
                data: {
                    "cmd" : "update",
                    "id" : user.id,
                    "name" : user.name,
                    "sip" : user.sip,
                    "session" : user.session, 
                    "ip" : user.ip
                },
                dataType: "html",
                success: function(msg){
                    str=msg.split(",");
                    $("#OnlineStatus").html(str[0]);
                    $("#OnlineScreen").html(str[1]);
                }
            });
            setTimeout("updateStatus()",1000);
        }

    }

    func.updateStatus();

};

})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use the `arguments.callee`, a reference to the current function

```
setTimeout(arguments.callee,1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no function named `updateStatus` in there. There is, however, a `func.updateStatus` function so your [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/window.setTimeout) should look like this:

```
setTimeout(func.updateStatus, 1000);
```

Also, calling `setTimeout` (or [`setInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/window.setInterval)) with a string as the first argument is generally considered bad form, you're better off passing a function as the first argument.